# What do I do with Oracle Ascension coins?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I've gotten roughly 10-15 Oracle Ascension coins during my time playing FFXV. They seemed to have some sort of significance, since I got my first one from Ardyn in a cutscene. What exactly do I do with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are a type of collectible in Final Fantasy 15. The more you have found, the more you will be allowed to buy from Alessio, who can be found in a cafe in the northeastern area of Altissia.

The full breakdown of unlocks can be seen [here](http://www.accelerated-ideas.com/finalfantasy15/what-are-oracle-ascension-coins-for.aspx):

- 1 - Megalixir
- 4 - Fire/Ice/Lightning Crest
- 8 - Dark Crest
- 20 - Mighty Guard
- 30 - Stone Wall
- 40 - Ribbon

The Ribbon is exceptionally useful as it prevents **all** status ailments. Thus, it is well worth your time to seek out Oracle Ascension coins. A detailed guide on where to find them can be seen [here](http://www.gosunoob.com/final-fantasy-xv/oracle-ascension-coin-locations-map/).